# How can I avoid these comments getting rendered in a SQL Server stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, notepad++, ddl

I'm creating a large SQL file with all of my ddl scripts for a database deployment. I'm using code folding in Notepad++ to be able to provide some structure and separation to the scripts. I've configured this in Notepad++:

```
--#region => GetAllUsers

CREATE SPROC GetAllUsers
AS
BEGIN
END

--#endregion
--#region => GetAllGroups

CREATE SPROC GetAllGroups
AS
BEGIN
END

--#endregion
```

This works as expected but the problem is that when I choose to modify `GetAllUsers` in SSMS, the output looks like this:

```
CREATE SPROC GetAllUsers
AS
BEGIN
END

--#endregion
--#region => GetAllGroups
```

Is there a way I can maintain the code folding structure but avoid the additional code-folding comments from getting added at the end of the stored procedure definition?

Answer (score 3):

you need a GO between the create statements

Comment: batch isolating comments (GO) outside of the create grammar will provide the desired results